# using XAML Map Control to add a heatmap layer on a map based on OpenStreetMap from C# VS2013 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, openstreetmap

I am trying to use XAML MAP control (https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/) to add a heatmap layer on a map based on OpenStreetMap from C# VS2013 WPF.

I have added the heatmap image to the map by setting north, south, east and west latitude/longitude in MainWindow.xaml.

But, I need the locations in the heatmap to be shown in the correct locations with same latitude and longitude in the map as they are created from the input file not just pasting the image to the map.

Example, the given input is :

```
   Logitude,    latitude,    value
       -77.85      42.96      9798
```

There are 0.5 million locations in the input file.

I would like to show the locations in the map as heatmap points. In the above example, the point is located at New York State. I would like to show it on a map with some colors that are assigned according to the value in a legend specified beforehand.

Also, because 0.5 million points are shown on a map may not be a good view when zoom level is large e.g. 15. So, I hope that when I zoom in the map, the heatmap points can be merged to one point at different aggregated geo-level.

For example, if there 5000 points in one zip code area, at zoom level > 12, I only show one point in one zip code area at the zip-code centroid or just make the zipcode area to be colored as a polygon with only one color.

When zoom level at 8 < level < 12, I only need to show county level points in the pattern same as above.

When zoom level at 3 < level < 5, I only need to show state level points in the pattern same as above.

When zoom level at  level < 3, I only need to show U.S. country level points in the pattern same as above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you have created a bitmap from your heatmap data, it should cover a certain area in world coordinates. So you could add a MapImage with the appropriate bounds (west, east, south, north) to the map and put the heatmap bitmap in its Source property. You may also add a handler for the ViewportChanged event and update the MapImage according to your needs.

Comment: yes, I have created the heatmap as a bitmap jpeg and also set up the bounds in the MainWindow.xmal file. it was added to the map. But, I need to show the points on the map at the correct lat/lon and currently, I only put the jpeg on the map. It is impossible to exactly get the bounds of the heatmap to align with the US map only by setting 4 lat/lon. thanks

Comment: You are creating the heatmap, so you should know its bounds. If you apply these bounds to the `East`, `West`, `South` and `North` properties of a MapImage, it would automatically show in the right location. Of course this requires that the heatmap uses the same map projection as the OpenStreetMap data, i.e. the so-called "Web Mercator" or "Pseudo Mercator" projection.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a derived MapImageLayer and override its `UpdateImage` to create a heatmap bitmap on the fly. This would of course only be a sensible approach, if creating the bitmap doesn't take too much time.

```
public class HeatmapImage : MapImageLayer
{
    protected override void UpdateImage(
        double west, double east, double south, double north, int width, int height)
    {
        BitmapSource bitmap = ... // create heatmap here
        UpdateImage(west, east, south, north, bitmap);
    }
}
```

You would then simply add the `HeatmapImage` to the map, and you're done:

```
<map:Map TileLayer="{x:Static map:TileLayer.OpenStreetMapTileLayer}">
    <local:HeatmapImage />
</map:Map>
```

Note that the map image in the bitmap would have to be created using the [Web Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator) projection.

---

EDIT: To give you an idea how a MapImage works, take a look at the following XAML snippet from the sample application in XAML Map Control. It displays an image with the given lat/lon bounds as an overlay in the map control. The actual image is a aerial image tile copied from Google Maps:

```
<map:MapImage South="53.54031" North="53.74871" West="8.08594" East="8.43750"
              Source="10_535_330.jpg"/>
```

Comment: @Clements, thanks!, I created the hitmap by http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88956/GHeat-NET. But, it is very slow. It cost 20 minutes to create a heatmap for 500k locations, If I mark the locations on the map directly from  XAML Map Control as circles that has different colors according to the values of the locations based on a legend, it is efficient in XAML Map Control ? How long time to do this for 500k points ? for 30k points ? for 3k points ?

Comment: 3k may be ok. 500k (and certainly also 30k) is way beyond what is possible, considering that every map item is a WPF UIElement. You would have to find a way to pre-process your data and put as less items as possible on the map. I could think of an approach where you create a derived ImageTileSource to create heatmap tiles, which would be 256x256 bitmaps like the OpenStreetMap tiles.

Comment: @Clements, suppose that we have 30k zip code areas in a US map, if I assign a value for each zip code and set a color for each value based on a legend of color vs. value. I only need to do coloring (not adding pushpin) for each zip-code polygon on the map from OSM. it is possbile to do this by XAML map control ? Does this still cost a long time ? How long ? 10 minutes ? thanks

Comment: 30k filled polygons? Impossible to re-create on the fly. You would somehow have to create bitmaps in advance and provide them by a derived ImageTileSource. No idea how long that would take to calculate.

Comment: @Clemns, the "east, south, north, west" can only be lat/lon ? Can it be point, pixel, milliter, inch  or point ? In "System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit", there are no lat/longitude. In System.Drawing. public RectangleF GetBounds(ref GraphicsUnit pageUnit) return "RectangleF" as  the bounds of the image.  thanks!

Comment: The bounds are in world coordinates, i.e. latitude and longitude. You should know these values, as you are creating the heatmap for a certain area of thw world.

Comment: I use "GraphicsUnit gu = GraphicsUnit.World; RectangleF imageBounds = canvasImage.GetBounds(ref gu);" but it only give me the pixel units.

Comment: The screen coordinates of the canvasImage are irrelevant here. You don't need them. `GraphicsUnit.World` has *nothing* to do with lat/lon coordinates. Note that no API call can give you these values, because you are the only one who knows them. You have to set the four properties of the MapImage.

Comment: Ok, I see. But, when I created the heatmap, the lat/lon have been transformed to pixel. I just got some points on a bitmap. Are there some ways to create the heatmap from XAML Map control to get a bitmap with bounds as lat/lon and then show it as a mapImage in OSM map ?

Comment: Don't know how to tell this in a simpler way. When you create the heatmap, you (hopefully) know the W/E/S/N bounds of the area of your data (where west and east are longitudes, and north and south are latitudes). The created bitmap does not know anything about world bounds. Now comes the important part: you put the bitmap into the `Source` property of a MapImage, and **also** set the `West`, `East`, `South`and `North` properties **to the values with which you created the bitmap**. That's all (except that the bitmap would also have to use the correct Web Mercator projection).

Comment: See my edit to the answer to get an idea of what I am talking about. Now image that you provide the `Source` bitmap that covers the area of your data.

Comment: Thanks. I use the max/min lat/lon of the input points as the bounding box. But, the bitmap has a magin arund the points so that when I put it on the map. All points cannot be put on the correct locations even though I use the bounding box as the W/E/S/N lat/lon in XAML Map control. I have set margins as "0,0,0,0" in "<WindowsPresentation:GMapControl Name="myMap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="900"/>", but the result bitmap still have the margin.

Comment: Sorry, now you're asking about GMapControl. I can't help you with that. Please note however, that a bitmap has no margin by itself. A margin would be set on a control that displays a bitmap.